# multiprocessing.pool does not terminate (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, terminate

I have an issue with multiprocessing.pool. Even though the exit condition defined in the while loop below is met, my workers never exit. After the last worker is done with its job the while loop is not entered anymore. However, the child processes do not terminate as I would expect but simply idle and the main process does not continue. This is on Ubuntu.

The last output is "Done" and nothing happens after that. If I add the line I commented out below, i.e. `handler.get()` the program runs through and terminates correctly without error (using one process only). Maybe there is an obvious error here but I am out of ideas, any help is appreciated!

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
queue = manager.Queue()
lock = manager.Lock()

finished = manager.list()
active = manager.list()
pending = manager.list()

for core in core_list:
     queue.put(core)
     pending.put(core.id)

while len(pending) > 0:
    print "Submit jobs"
    core = queue.get(block=True)
    handler = pool.apply_async(solve_core, (core, core_list, params))
    #handler.get()

pool.close()
pool.join()

def solve_core(core, core_list, params):
    lock.acquire()
    pending.remove(core.id)
    active.append(core.id)
    lock.release()

    # Process some data...

    lock.acquire()
    active.remove(core.id)
    finished.append(core.id)
    for new_core in core_list:
        if some_condition:
            queue.put(new_core)
            pending.append(new_core.id)
    lock.release()
    print "Done"
```

Comment: your code example is not runnable, how could other debug it for you?

Comment: I was hoping/assuming there is a structural error that is obvious for someone with more experience. Apparently that was true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obvious race condition error, despite there are many more.
Your program depend subprocess to empty `pending` list, but as you are using `apply_async`, subprocess may not able change `pending` list as quick as master's `while len(pending) > 0` loop, then master process will call more times of `queue.get(block=True)` than the size of the queue, as a result, master process blocked on `queue.get`.

Comment: Hmm okay, let me try to fix this and update my answer with a runable example! Thanks a lot!